# Reload page right before submit a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, refresh

I have a webpage that contains a form, and i need to refresh the page right before the form is submitted. Is there a way to have the Submit button refresh the current page and then submit the form to the proper php document?

I am using a general form with the submit button looking like

```
<input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
```

Comment: Why would you want to accomplish this and perhaps I can come up with a better solution for you - this is a strange request.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Doing this would cancel the submitted form request.

Comment: In the question you are asking us to fix your solutions ... How about instead you explain, what you are you trying to solve.

Comment: the way the check boxes are set up, it doesnt clear the form data. Also i am doing this because i stupidly set up my page so that the form is submitted in php, but i have a autoupdating value in javascript that i need to be sent as well. So i sent the javascript value to a hidden input field and i need the page to refresh so the proper value is set to the hidden input field before he form is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the page - do not pursue making this problem larger than it already is. I think it's some tunnel vision, you've made some mistakes on how you have setup your form or page, and now you are trying to continue down the wrong path instead of correcting your original problem.

Refreshing the page to submit some javascript data and then submit the form etc... is incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Best of luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `form` a `target` to submit it in a new window and bind an event handler to it that refreshes the page on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to get some data from the server that's required to submit the form, it's possible to do (though it's not the best way to handle it). You'll need to intercept form submit, stop the events, perform an AJAX request to the server and then submit the form from code.